# System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject at method fine

Tags: apex, visualforce

When im running the below soql its work fine

```
SELECT BillingCountry,BillingCity, Industry, (SELECT Id, Name,Amount , StageName FROM Opportunities) FROM Account  WHERE BillingCountry = 'USA'
```

its work fine but when i customized this query into

```
SELECT BillingCountry,BillingCity, Industry, (SELECT Id, Name,Amount , StageName FROM Opportunities) FROM Account
```

salesforce returing this error.

Here is the method where i run this query

```
public PageReference find() 
    {         
        String id = UserInfo.getUserId();
        User activeUser = [Select Email From User where id = :id limit 1];
        String email = activeUser.Email;

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        req.setEndpoint('http://52.37.182.4/public/checkUser/'+email);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setCompressed(false);
        req.setBody('key1=value1&key2=value2');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

        try {
            res = http.send(req);
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        }

        Boolean userExsist = (Boolean)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), Boolean.class);

        if(!userExsist)
        {
            showPopup();
            return null;
        }                            

        lstResultWrapper = new List<ResultWrapper>();
        for(Account c : [SELECT BillingCountry,BillingCity, Industry, (SELECT Id, Name,Amount , StageName FROM Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE BillingCountry='USA'])
        {
                req.setEndpoint('http://52.37.182.4/public/checkDeal/'+c.Opportunities[0].Name);
                req.setMethod('GET');
                req.setCompressed(false);
                req.setBody('key1=value1&key2=value2');
                req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

                try {
                    res = http.send(req);
                } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
                    System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
                    return null;
                }

                Boolean dealExsist = (Boolean)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), Boolean.class);

// error indicating on the below line       
                ResultWrapper result = new ResultWrapper(c,c.Opportunities, !dealExsist);
                lstResultWrapper.add(result);                                    

        }

        return null;
    }
```

**Edited** :
[image]
[image]

**Visual Force page**

```
<apex:pageBlock id="tableId2">
                 <apex:outputText value="{!result}"></apex:outputText> 
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstResultWrapper}" var="items" id="table">

                    <apex:column headerValue="Deal Title"> 
                    <apex:outputText value="{!items['opportunity'].Name}"/> 
                    </apex:column> 

                    <apex:column headerValue="Deal Value"> 
                    <apex:outputText value="{!items['opportunity'].Amount}"/> 
                    </apex:column> 

                    <apex:column headerValue="Stage"> 
                    <apex:outputText value="{!items['opportunity'].StageName}"/> 
                    </apex:column> 

                    <apex:column headerValue="Industry"> 
                    <apex:outputText value="{!items['account'].Industry}"/> 
                    </apex:column> 

                    <apex:column headerValue="Country"> 
                    <apex:outputText value="{!items['account'].BillingCountry}"/> 
                    </apex:column> 

                    <apex:column headerValue="City"> 
                    <apex:outputText value="{!items['account'].BillingCity}"/> 
                    </apex:column> 


                    <apex:column headerValue="Action"> 
                        <apex:commandButton value="Find Clozer" onclick="displayResult" action="{!createDeal}" rendered="{!IF(items['isCreated'], false, true)}" rerender="tableId2,table" >
                            <apex:param name="title" value="{!items['opportunity'].Name}" assignTo="{!title}" />
                             <apex:param name="dealValue" value="{!items['opportunity'].Amount}" assignTo="{!dealValue}" />
                             <apex:param name="stageName" value="{!items['opportunity'].StageName}" assignTo="{!stageName}" />
                             <apex:param name="ind" value="{!items['account'].Industry}" assignTo="{!ind}" />
                             <apex:param name="count" value="{!items['account'].BillingCountry}" assignTo="{!count}" />
                             <apex:param name="cty" value="{!items['account'].BillingCity}" assignTo="{!cty}" /> 
                        </apex:commandButton>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Add LIMIT 1 in your soql

Comment: at what line you are seeing this error ?

Comment: You can do `for(List<Account>` ... > but I don't know what your trying to do

Comment: Are you sure that line `lstResultWrapper.add(result); ` throws an exception of type `System.QueryException` ? It seems rather impossible.

Comment: @Himanshu i put a comment above the line where the error occur

Comment: @EricSSH ive post some error which might help you to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your ResultWrapper which currently accepting single opportunity but you are passing c.Opportunities which is list of opportunity so modify your ResultWrapper to accept list.

```
ResultWrapper result = new ResultWrapper(c,c.Opportunities, !dealExsist);
```

Wrapper class

```
public class ResultWrapper{
  public Account account {get;set;} 
  public List<Opportunity> opportunity {get;set;} 
  public Boolean isCreated {get;set;}

  public ResultWrapper(Account acc,List<Opportunity> opt,Boolean alreadyCreated) { 
         this.account = acc; 
         this.opportunity = opt; 
         this.isCreated = alreadyCreated; 
 } 
}
```

I don't know what is your logic behind this wrapper class but if you want to user single opportunity there is no need to modify wrapper class only pass single opportunity as shown below

```
ResultWrapper result = new ResultWrapper(c,c.Opportunities[0], !dealExsist);
```

Comment: here is my wrapper class
 public class ResultWrapper{
        
        public Account account {get;set;}
        public Opportunity opportunity {get;set;}
        public Boolean isCreated {get;set;}
        
        public ResultWrapper(Account acc,Opportunity opt,Boolean alreadyCreated)
        {
            this.account = acc;
            this.opportunity = opt;
            this.isCreated = alreadyCreated;
        }
    }

Comment: what changs should i make there

Comment: check the updated code

Comment: i am using the wrapper class to display the data into the datatable.For making you more clear here is the code.I update my post pls have a look

Comment: i assume that you have one single opportunity for every account if yes gor for last line of my answer don't modify wrapper class

Comment: Basically im my app is searching the opportunity which match with country name.So some time it could return one or more opportunities for a perticuller country

Comment: but in that case how you will display them in page block table ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38318/discussion-between-moin-khan-and-himanshu).